# A map $T: C([0,1]) \to C([0,1])$ that is a contraction in the unit closed ball but doesn't have fixed point

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Consider the space $C([0,1])$ with $\sup$ norm and define $T: C([0,1]) \to C([0,1])$ by $(T(x))(t) = (1-t)x(t) + t \sin \frac{1}{t}$.

Define $B$ the unit closed ball of $C([0,1])$. Show that

$(i)$ $T(B) \subseteq B$

$(ii)$ $\forall x,y \in B, d(T(x),T(y)) \leq d(x,y)$ but $T$ doesn't have fixed point.

My attempt on $(i)$: 
Let $x \in B$. Then $(T(x)(t)) = (1-t)x(t) + t \sin \frac{1}{t} $ and I need to prove $\sup_{t \in [0,1]} \{ |(T(x))(t)| \} \leq 1$.

$ \sup_{t \in [0,1]} \{ |(T(x))(t)| \} = \sup_{t \in [0,1]} \{ |(1-t)x(t) + t \sin \frac{1}{t}| \} \leq  \sup_{t \in [0,1]} \{ |(1-t)x(t)| \} +  \sup_{t \in [0,1]} \{ t \sin \frac{1}{t}| \} \leq  \sup_{t \in [0,1]} \{ |(x(t)| \} + \sup_{t \in [0,1]} \{ |tx(t)| \} +  \sup_{t \in [0,1]} \{ t \sin \frac{1}{t}| \} $

But $\sup_{t \in [0,1]} \{ t \sin \frac{1}{t}| \}$ is already 1, then this wouldn't work...

My attempt on $(ii)$
$d(T(x),T(y)) = d((1-t)x(t) + t \sin \frac{1}{t},(1-t)y(t) + t \sin \frac{1}{t}) = \| (1-t)x(t) + t \sin \frac{1}{t} - (1-t)y(t) - t \sin \frac{1}{t} \| = \| (1-t)(x(t)-y(t)) \| = \| x(t) - y(t) -tx(t) + ty(t) \| \leq \|x(t)-y(t) \| + \|t(y(t)-x(t)) \| \leq  \|x(t)-y(t) \| + |t|\|(y(t)-x(t)) \| $

but that would be still bigger than what I need to get:

$d(x,y) = \| x - y \| = \sup_{t \in [0,1]} \{ x(t)-y(t) \}$

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: In your attempt on (ii), notice that $|(1-t)(x(t)-y(t))| = |1-t| \, |x(t)-y(t)| \le |x(t) - y(t)|$ for all $t \in [0,1]$. Then take supremum over all such $t$.

In your attempt on (i), notice that $|(1-t)x(t) + t y(t)| \le |(1-t)x(t)| + |t y(t)| = (1-t)|x(t)| + t|y(t)|$ for $t \in [0,1]$. By definition of $B$, if $x$ and $y$ are in $B$, then this last sum is bounded from above by $(1-t) + t = 1$, hence the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $|t\sin1/t|<1$ on $[0,1] $. In (i), you have $$|(1-t)x (t)|+|t\sin1/t|<(1-t)+t=1. $$ In (2), $$|(1-t)(x (t)-y (t)=(1-t)\,|x (t)-y (t)|\leq|x (t)-y (t)|. $$

Comment: Thanks! I understood and completed the details for (i) and (ii), except the last part, proving that there is no fixed point, which I'm probably not doing it right. . Here's my attempt: Suppose by absurd there exists a fixed point $x(t)$. Then $x(t) = (1-t)x(t) + t \sin(\frac{1}{t}) \Rightarrow t x(t) = t \sin(\frac{1}{t})$. If $t>0$, then $x(t) = \sin(\frac{1}{t})$, which is not continuous on $[0,1]$. If $t=0$, then the equation doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes, that's right.